# atualizar coluna em tabela - postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Sou iniciante em pgSQL... Utilizo a versao 9.5.0 e preciso atualizar uma coluna toda vez que um novo registro for inserido.
A coluna deve ser preenchida a partir dos valores inseridos em area_pol e area_ofi.

estou tentando criar essa function para atender minha necessidade:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sch_cap.fc_atualiza_dif_area()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
    UPDATE
        sch_cap.tbl_cap
    SET
        dif_area = abs(100 - (tbl_cap.area_pol / (tbl_cap.area_ofi * 100)));
END;
```

$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tg_atualiza_dif_area BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON sch_cap.tbl_cap FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE sch_cap.fc_atualiza_dif_area();

Porém quando tento inserir um registro, é apresentado a seguinte msg: 
ERROR:  stack depth limit exceeded
HINT:  Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 2048kB), after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sua TRIGGER é executada a cada UPDATE e ela mesma também executa um UPDATE, gerando um loop infinito. Daí o HINT te avisando que está estourando o limite de memória reservado para recursividade de pilha.

Uma saída simples para isso é só executar a FUNCTION caso seja uma "instância" de primeiro nível da TRIGGER, e ignorar UPDATES que venham de outras iterações, quebrando o loop.

Para isso utilize a FUNCTION [`pg_trigger_depth()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-info.html), que retorna um número que representa o nível de recursividade da execução atual. Assim, sua TRIGGER deve ser condicionada ao retorno `0` dessa função, utilizando a cláusula `WHEN`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_atualiza_dif_area 
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
    ON sch_cap.tbl_cap FOR EACH ROW 
    WHEN (pg_trigger_depth() = 0) 
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE sch_cap.fc_atualiza_dif_area();
```

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado !